# Laravel hash password in controller

Tags: php, laravel, hash

I want to make a password hash inside the Controller so that the information is stored to the database.

My storing function is;

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), ['fullname' => 'required',
        'email'  => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'username'  => 'required|max:255|unique:users',
        'password'  => 'required',]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {

       return response()->json([
        '1' => 'Your information not stored!',
      ]);       
    }
    else {
    $newuser = new User;
    $newuser -> fullname = request('fullname');
    $newuser -> email = request('email');
    $newuser -> password = request('password');
    $newuser -> username = request('username');
    $newuser -> status = 1;
    $newuser -> role_id = 1;
    $newuser -> save();
    return response()->json([
        '2' => 'Your information stored successfuly!',
    ]);
    }
```

This works correctly. But, I want to hash the password.

```
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/hashing
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/how-to-hash-user-input-password-when-using-form-validation-in-form-request-laravel-5


 public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value);
}
```

This does not work. Does any of you have any suggestions?

Comment: dd($newuser ) before save,  provide the code here

Comment: show us your full model class

Comment: `$newuser->password = bcrypt(request('password'));` is all you need to do.

Comment: he is trying to do with mutator i guess

Comment: $newuser->password = bcrypt($request('password'));

Answer (score 3):

just change

```
 $newuser -> password = bcrypt(request('password'));
```

Comment: Can not access Request from model

Comment: @Mahdi Sure you can, the `request()` helper and the `Request` facade can access the request object anywhere during it's  lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

**Change**:

```
$newuser->password = request('password');
```

**To:**

```
$newuser->password = bcrypt(request('password'));
```

See the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/hashing)

Comment: Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column &#039;password&#039; at row 1 (SQL: insert into `users` (`fullname`, `email`, `password`, `username`, `status`, `role_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (sediq2222, sharif22@gmail.com, $2y$10$HvqJ48R7eDlcq/T.kM2gqOYnPVzYqkLd5njo8JmLYt9DI9AGUTS9K, karimiauifiu12a222, 1, 1, 2018-01-30 04:35:10, 2018-01-30 04:35:10)) in file C:\xampp\htdocs\Vers_La_Lune\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 664
Stack trace: